# Configure default name node port in hadoop 2.6

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to update default port of name node and datanode (Hadoop 2.6), I did required configuration in core-site.xml.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:64965</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:64956</value>
</property>
```

I also formated name node after changes but still I am not able to see any change s on web UI means when I click on
    https://localhost:64965 it's showing page not found.
and same can access using  https://localhost:50070.

So it means it still pointing to default port.

Any one can help me where I am lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the process is still running on the previous port 50070.

1.kill the process using,

```
netstat -plten |grep java
```

there you will find

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       1636154     14878/java
```

kill the process using process number

```
kill -9 14878
```

which will kill the process forcefully.

2.now format the name nodes and run the server