# Hadoop seem to run on console, but can't login from the browser

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

I have been trying to use mahout to create a recommender and in setting the environment, I have set up hadoop on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. I hope it has been install successfully. When I try `hadoop version` it gives me the following response.

`Hadoop 2.6.0
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r e3496499ecb8d220fba99dc5ed4c99c8f9e33bb1
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-11-13T21:10Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 18e43357c8f927c0695f1e9522859d6a
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar`

After I run the `start-all.sh` script, I tried to access hadoop using the browser from the url http://localhost:50070/ and the response I am getting is that the `web page is not available`

The tutorial that I have been following suggest this web interface to be checked out by the followers and the mahout installation part is only mentioned after this. So, is there anything wrong with the installation or am I missing something?

Edit: when I access http://localhost:8088/ it is working

Answer (score 0):

kill your process running on port 50070 and restart the hadoop.Next time it should open web console.refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964626/configure-default-name-node-port-in-hadoop-2-6/32967671#32967671).

Comment: When I checked for processes on port 50070, I did not find any.

Comment: have you tried changing port number other than 50070?

Comment: I don't know how to, can you please instruct me?

Comment: open **coresite.xml** and other configuration files you have given 50070 and then change 50070 to 9000.